# Use a binary search to find max of a function

Tags: c++, c++11

My task is to use a binary search to write a method optimal() that finds the max value of a function of unsigned ints. The domain of the function is 0 to 2^64 - 1. I know no information about the max value or the max index. The only information I have is a method, double func(unsigned int x); which returns the value of x at the max. I also know that the function is either strictly increasing, strictly decreasing, or increasing to a point, then decreasing.

I attempted to check for strictly increasing functions:

```
unsigned int optimal()
{
unsigned int x, y, mid, size, start;
size = 2e32 - 1;
start = 0;
x = 1;
y = size - 1;

if ((func(start) < func(x)) && (func(y) < func(size))) return size;
if ((func(start) > func(x)) && (func(y) > func(size))) return start;

return 0;
}
```

which didn't work.

Comment: Is `func(2^64 - 2)` pseudo-code, or is that what you had in your code?  (Hard to know, since you did not provide your actual code.)

Comment: Instead of describing your approach, [edit] your question with a [mcve].

Comment: A minimun reproduction code/repo would help us find out your coding problems

Comment: @Eljay it's psuedocode, I didn't provide my actual code because all I had actually written were attempts to check for a strictly decreasing or increasing function, which didn't work

Comment: Your if statement logic seems to be incorrect, it should be  `if (func(0) > func(1)) then returns func(0)` for decreasing function `else if (func(2^64 - 2) < func(2^64 - 1)) then returns func(2^64 - 1)` for increasing function

Comment: `size = 2e32 - 1` is 9967888, which is significantly less than 18446744073709551615 (2⁶⁴ - 1).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the function seems to be an increasing/decreasing/increasing-then-decreasing array once you spread the input number out in array from 0 to n. You can use binary search to find the peak in the function. For each mid point, you can determine if the part of the array is decreasing, increasing or peak and then locate which part of the array likely to have the peak. You can find more details and explanation in [this article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-the-maximum-element-in-an-array-which-is-first-increasing-and-then-decreasing/)

```
int maxInBitonic(int arr[], int low, int high)
{
    // find out the size of the array
    // for edge case checking
    int n = high + 1;

    // main code goes as follows
    while (low <= high) {
        // find out the mid
        int mid = low + (high - low) / 2;
        
        // if mid index value is maximum
        if(arr[mid] > arr[mid+1] and arr[mid] > arr[mid-1])
            return arr[mid];

        // reducing search space by moving to right
        else if (arr[mid] < arr[mid + 1])
            low = mid + 1;

        // reducing search space by moving to left
        else
            high = mid - 1;
    }

    return arr[high];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I am unfamiliar with C++ to assist you in code, but these points might help.

1. What about checking for the gradient of the function and moving in the same direction. Since your function (as you describe it) only have one maximal point, I think this is the correct approach.
2. Gradient calculation: `grad(x1 - x2) = (f(x1) - f(x2))/ (x1 - x2)`
3. Apply Binary search to restrict the search domain. So if you check the gradient between `0` and `1` and it's positive for example. Then we move to the right side along the gradient since we know the function is increasing moving to the side of `1`. Then we move our search to between `1` and `2^64 - 1`, cutting the search domain in half. Rinse and repeat.
4. So if we keep doing this, at some point we either hit gradient of 0 or very small gradient value (`~0`), and even your gradient value can be oscillating between negative and positive, meaning you are close to a local max/min (but in our function's case, it is a max). Here you can manually tweak your search to more quickly converge to that final result if needed. Or just decide to stop on a estimated value.
5. But since you're doing binary search, i think it will converge quickly anyways. Step 4 is usually needed in gradient decend where we have no idea about the domain size. This case however, there is a domain size and binary search is good fit.

Hope this help, good luck with your work!

Comment: What information does a gradient calculation between 0 and 1 give me that a simple check of f(0) and f(1) does not? Also, how does restricting my size by 1 value cut my search domain in half?

Comment: Ah yes I guess you're correct, gradient value is only valid as a "velocity" in gradient decend method, it gives you how fast your function is increasing/decreasing so that we can move along it. So in our case of binary search it is not very do much compare to simple function value check.
As for search domain, I'm saying that if the function is increasing, check the right side instead of the left side, which cuts the domain in half.